# WARN: Unable to auto-create type

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I'm trying to construct a object with parameteres, like this:

```
PublicationResource resourceAux = new PublicationResource (publication: pub, resource: res);
if (resourceAux)
{
    resourceAux.save(flush: true, failOnError: true);
}
```

I receive this error:

```
WARN 2012-11-20 22:52:35,775 [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.GrailsDataBinder] Unable to auto-create type, Groovy Runtime error: java.lang.InstantiationException
```

Comment: Put the definition of PublicationResource

Comment: It seems that your PublicationResource or another domain class have a type that's not mapped to a database type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of either publication or resource in the class PublicationResource is  not and instatiatable type (ie abstract or interface).